# Defining black-box zones in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have the following requirement - custom widgets that contain dynamically created but non-editable in a WYSIWYG way content (loaded from outside of the editor) and some of the widgets can also contain input fields that should be editable for the user.

Is there a way to tell CKEditor that it shouldn't touch particular elements (zones) and leave them as they are, or is such functionality planned in the near future, or are there any hints on how to implement it myself? Or is there another approach for implementing these requirements?

**What I tried so far**:
After the widget is initialized I manually create the dynamic content and attach it to the widget element using the native DOM apis. However CKEditor still decorates my elements and prevents me from focusing the input fields when they get clicked (I suspect it uses some kind of mutation observer :)). I attached my own event handler like this:

```
input.onclick = function(event) {....
```

where I tried to stop the event bubbling in order to prevent the CKEditor from stopping input focusing but without any success.

**P.S.**
I know that CKEditor is a WYSIWYG editor and such things are not supported out of the box and are not directly related to WYSIWYG editing but these are the requirements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220508/ckeditor-with-noneditable-islands

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't help in solving my problem.