# CKEditor with noneditable islands

Tags: ckeditor

How can we have non-editable areas in a non-readOnly area?
Notice I still need most of the editor have editable content, so using readOnly mode is not an option. Setting `contentEditable=true` for those areas doesn't work, it seems like CKEditor strips all `contentEditable` values of it's children tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKEditor 4.3 introduced [Widget System](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets) which solves exactly this issue - it allows you to have non-editable fragments in the content. Actually, it allows you to do much more than that, because these non-editable islands may then have editable fragments, you can restrict per nested editable what features are enabled, etc.

Some links for the start:

- [Introduction to Widgets](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets),
- [Widgets SDK introduction](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro),
- [Creating a Simple CKEditor Widget (Part 1)](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1),
- [Widget API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget).

And some live examples:

- [Simplebox plugin](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/simplebox.html),
- [Captioned images](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/captionedimage.html),
- [Code snippets with syntax highlighting](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/codesnippet.html),
- [Placeholder](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/placeholder.html).

PS. I think you should also read about the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf).